# Name Hypocorism List

Tags: validation

Does anybody know of a public list of name hypocorisms (a contracted form of a given name, such as Tony from Anthony, Rosy for Rosemarie or Vicky from Victoria)?

Comment: You don't mean <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synonym">synonyms</a> but <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocoristic">hypocorisms</a>, right? The difference matters: I know a few online synonym dictionaries, but no hypocoristic ones.

Comment: it seems I need a list more than I thought

Comment: (what? no html support in comments? :-))

Comment: Okay, I was saying that what you seem to need is a mapping of hypocorisms, not synonyms. Check Wikipedia for the different (can't embed URLs here, apparently).

Comment: Yes I suppose it would be a hypocorism, I had no idea there was such a word but:
"a contracted form of a given name, such as Tony from Anthony, Rosy for Rosemarie or Vicky from Victoria."

Comment: @CesarGon: Just put the bare URL.  Comment formatting is pretty limited, compared to answers.

Comment: it lets you do *italic*, **bold**, and `code` but that's about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a perl module that can do it here:
http://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::EN::Nickname

It seems to base it's results on a simple textfile which can be downloaded here:
http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/BRIANL/Lingua-EN-Nickname-1.17/nicknames.txt

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a [list](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_given_names) of some addition names that a that are not in the [list](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/BRIANL/Lingua-EN-Nickname-1.17/nicknames.txt) provided by @rjmunro.